# Converting RGB byte array to BufferedImage

Tags: java

This is the code how I convert BufferedImage to byte array:

```
public void parseBufferedImage(BufferedImage image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y), true);
            outputStream.write(color.getRed());
            outputStream.write(color.getGreen());
            outputStream.write(color.getBlue());
            outputStream.write(color.getAlpha());
        }
    }
    image.flush();
    byte[] data = outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

I need to convert byte[] data back to an image, but I have only byte[] array so I do not know image size.

I want to save byte[] as a png, so I would be open to suggestions of another method.

Comment: Once you've streamed an NxM image into an array of NxM bytes, you've lost all information about the image dimensions.

Comment: BTW its from minecraft, and if i send byte array to the client, it will render it as a player skin so it must be possible I guess. Unfortunately its MCPE so its written in C++ and I cannot see its code.

Comment: `Or I want to save byte[] as a png` - You can save the image as a png using `ImageIO.write(...)`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou That isn't true in a literal sense. The image header still exists.